# echoing an html value inside html

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I echo inside an html tag? I read some articles here and I understood that I have to put the all HTML tag inside the PHP, but when I do, it won't show the correct layout. I mean, it puts it in the top of the page instead of showing it where it belong. How can I make this work? Attached two pictures to explain my broken english better

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='inner'> <h2 class='major'>How many accounts</h2> <p>We currently have ". $row["id"] . " accounts!</p></div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

And I would like to put only row id inside HTML tag because, in the HTML inside PHP it shows the first on the page, it doesn't show where it should belong.

```
<section id="four" class="wrapper alt style1">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="major">How many accounts</h2>
        <p>We currently have <?php echo $row["id"] ?> accounts!</p>
```

How it shows now: [image: Now]

How it should look
[image]

Comment: The HTML is output in the order that you echo it. There's nothing in your script that displays `DEVINA REALITATE` before the loop.

Comment: You could put all the HTML into a string and return that from your function, then echo it later.

Comment: I put the <?php> as the first code, then shut it with ?>   and started with <html> and after that I went only by html, everything is based on html. I tried to write "currently X accounts"  with PHP because only that way I can echo  the value from mysql

Comment: There's no difference between using `echo` with concatenated strings and going into and out of HTML mode with `?>` and `<?php`. It's just different styles, and has nothing to do with whether the header is printed first.

Comment: Why are you outputting the row id of a user table as the number of accounts anyway? As soon as you delete the first account, this will make your script tell nonsense ... (and don't even start with "but I will renumber my ids when I delete an account" now ...)

Comment: Thank you for your help, just figured it out how I can echo it. Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you echo $result->num_rows instead of id? What happen if someone close their account or you delete some rows in the middle of table?

Answer (score 0):

I have reached to an answer.

in HTML section I added `<?php echo $ID ?>`  and in the PHP section I modified it with

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ID = $row['id'];
}
```

Now script looks like this

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ID = $row['id'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

and the HTML part

```
<h2 class="major">How many Accounts?</h2>
<p>Currently we have <?php echo $ID ?> accounts.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable to your result.

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"]; }
```

Then anywhere in your html all you will have to do is the following.

```
    <?php echo $id; ?>
```

I hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: zeroknowledgee you answered yourself before I could finish typing :)